# How to save WKT polygon (OpenLayers) in PostGIS with PHP

Tags: postgis, polygon, openlayers

I have a web mapping application (using OpenLayers) that user can draw polygons in map interface and then the output WKT format create. Here is an example:

[Shows the use of WKT (Well known text) to draw features in OpenLayers](http://Here%20is%20an%20example)

How can I save this WKT polygons in PostGIS  database?

host = localhost

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: With OpenLayers, you might want to check out this tutorial: http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/06/openlayers-editing-wfs-t/ seems like something you would be looking to implement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already have a list of coordinates that describe your polygons, and also assuming you are using WGS84 projection then a simple query using [ST_GeomFromEWKT](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromEWKT.html) should work:

```
INSERT INTO my_polygons (the_geom, ...) VALUES (ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON((75.15 29.53 1,77 29 1,77.6 29.5 1,75.15 29.53 1))'), ...);
```

Comment: Those are quite big assumptions. I think the OP is asking how to get the GeoJSON from the drawn polygon, how to transfer it to a server, rather that the syntax of an insert statement -- correct though that may be.